# How to find the location ID of a service business with a hidden address?

Tags: location, google-places-api

I tried the Places API Web Service and...

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=exact+company+name+in+GMBlisting+city&key="YOUR_API_KEY"

But neither turned up the Location ID for this business that has a GMB listing for years and ranks well:

South West Garage Door Service Menifee CA 92584 USA

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you need to get a place ID of the business.

Please note that Places API search doesn't work with Service Area Businesses. The unique option to get a place ID for Service Area Business at the moment is using a place ID finder tool of Google My Business. This tool is located at

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/faq#associate_locations_using_placeid_1

The result of search is shown in the following screenshot

[image]

The place ID for 'South West Garage Door Service Menifee CA 92584 USA' is `ChIJcyJqBdCd3IARGHUMnQIgcGs`.

I hope this helps!

#### Update

It looks like Google removed the place Id finder tool from their Google My Business documentation.

As an alternative you can try method described in this post
https://www.launch2success.com/guide/find-any-google-id/

Search SAB Business in Google search and check the source code of the Write a review button. Find the `data-pid` attribute. It will contain the place ID as shown in my screenshot

[image]

Comment: Hi this is something that I am trying now and I am unable to use the link which you have stated in the comment above any other way ?

Comment: Unfortunately, Google removed this tool from their documentation. As an alternative try to use method described here: https://www.launch2success.com/guide/find-any-google-id/